# can someone explain fork and loop in system verilog?

Tags: loops, system-verilog, fork-join

I was going through [SV LRM section 9.3.2](https://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf) and got this doubt, i am pasting the example below for reference

```
for(int j=1; j <=3; ++j)
    fork
        automatic int k = j;
        begin
            .... # use k here
        end
    join_none
```

- Can someone explain me what is actually happening?
- What happens if i move the `automatic` variable outside the fork?

  ```
  for(int j=1; j <=3; ++j) begin
      automatic int k = j;
      fork
          begin
              .... # use k here
          end
      join_none
  end
  ```
- What happens if i move the loop inside the fork?

  ```
  fork
      for(int j=1; j <=3; ++j) begin
          automatic int k = j;
          begin
              .... # use k here
          end
      end
   join_none
  ```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To get an idea what is going on, modify the example in the LRM and run a simulation: `#k $write( "%0d", k );` to `#(4-k) $display( "k:%0d j:%0d", k, j);`. You will notice that the order of `k` is revere form the example in the LRM and that `j` is the same in each instance. There is no correct value for `j` as it undetermined per the LRM, therefore different simulators may display a different value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Moving the automatic variable outside the fork, but still inside the `begin/end` block of the `for` loop has the same effect. Each iteration of the loop gets its own local copy of `k` initialized with the current loop value of `j`. So you get three copies of `k` with the values 1,2, and 3. And each process spawned by the fork/join_none is bound to each local copy of `k`. Since the fork/join_none is inside the loop, you spawn three processes.

If you move the `for` loop inside the fork, then you only get one process spawned by the `fork` which has a loop. Then it doesn't matter if you use j or k because the code inside the loop executes sequentially.

Answer (score 0):

The effect of 1, 3 will be same and each threads of `fork...join` will take the proper values of j (j = 1,2,3... all will be taken).

But for the 2nd case, since you are assigning value to `k` outside of the thread, the last value of k will be taken for all threads.

Here is the sample code for each of your cases.

```
// Code 1
for(int j=1; j <=3; ++j)
    fork
        automatic int k = j;
        begin
          $display("Current Value - %0d", k);
        end
    join_none
    wait_fork;

// Output of Code 1
Current Value - 1
Current Value - 2
Current Value - 3

// Code 2
for(int j=1; j <=3; ++j)
begin
    automatic int k = j;
    fork
        begin
          $display("Current Value - %0d", k);
        end
    join_none
end
wait_fork;

// Output of Code 2
Current Value - 3
Current Value - 3
Current Value - 3

// Code 3
fork
    for(int j=1; j <=3; ++j)
      begin
        automatic int k = j;
        $display("Current Value - %0d", k);
      end
join_none
wait fork;

// Output of Code 3
Current Value - 1
Current Value - 2
Current Value - 3
```

Comment: your observation for code 2 contradicts the comment that Dave made. Code 1 and Code 3 gives the same output, we might be missing that code 1 actually runs in fork while code 3 runs sequentially.

Comment: Yup, but that's the output with VCS tool. And I think, every code will open up threads and won't run sequentially.